# Keyup event for iOS applications using swift

Tags: ios, swift, keyup

I want to use keyup/keydown event for my iOS application using swift as NSEvent is used for OS X not for iOS.

Any quick help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think iOS has that. There isn't a physical keyboard in iOS like there is in Mac OS (at least not by default). So I don't think iOS has the same key event mechanism that OS X does.

Comment: thank you for your quick response. Is there any way to deal with such key events in iOS?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Instead you usually use the `UITextFieldDelegate` or `UITextViewDelegate` methods like `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`. That method gets called each time the user makes a change to the field's contents, so it gets triggered on keypresses (also on copy/paste actions though, so it isn't a perfect analog)

Comment: `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` worked for me !! Thank you @Duncan C